# Is it a must to upgrade to windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

From this [link](http://www.classicstart8.com/detail/users-have-two-years-to-upgrade-to-windows):

> **Users Have Two Years to Upgrade to Windows® 8.1**
>
> Microsoft Windows® 8.1 was released October 18th for all Windows® 8 users. ... The lifecycle of this software update, known as Windows® Blue, will be the same as Windows® 8. General support will end January 1st, 2018, with extended support for necessary updates to last an additional 5 years.
>
> Customers have two years to upgrade to Windows® 8.1. After that time, the upgrade will be removed from the Windows Store, and Windows® 8 will not be supported or have access to future updates. So, it is recommended to follow the guidelines set by Microsoft® and update software as it is released.

Is the second paragraph correct, which makes the upgrade essentially mandatory?

Comment: Do you have the links that support these claims? I find it hard to believe this because people still get normal and security updates for Windows 7, let alone Windows 8. Windows 7 is far older than 8 so I find it hard to believe the updates part of your question. Windows 8.1 is kind of an "SP1" for Windows 8 but it doesn't pull in so many of the updates that a Service Pack generally would; it installs additional features such as the return of the "Start" button...

Comment: Why would anyone not want to update to 8.1? The update is free and 8.1 has a number of improvements compared to 8.0.

Comment: http://www.classicstart8.com/detail/users-have-two-years-to-upgrade-to-windows here's a link

Answer (score 1):

No, no need to drive crazy: according to **[Windows lifecycle fact sheet](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle)**  end of support of Windows 8 is at **January 10, 2023**.

Otherwise, why not [update to 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial):

> Windows 8.1 and Windows RT 8.1 build on Windows 8 and Windows RT, to
>   bring you enhancements in personalization, search, apps, the Windows
>   Store, and cloud connectivity, and has the security and reliability
>   features you expect from Windows. It's fast and made to work on a
>   variety of devices—especially on the new generation of touch devices.
>
> If your PC is currently running Windows 8 or Windows RT, it's free to
>   update to Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1. And unlike previous updates
>   to Windows, you'll get this update from the Windows Store.

Surely you need to [check the system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) first.

Comment: nope, he read it correctly, you are wrong about the updates

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you [must upgrade to Windows 8.1 to get new security updates](http://blogs.windows.com/business/2013/07/30/windows-8-1-enterprise-preview-now-available/).

> Windows 8 customers will have two years to move to Windows 8.1 after
>   the General Availability of the Windows 8.1 update to continue to
>   remain supported under Windows 8 lifecycle.

The [following FAQ shows](http://support2.microsoft.com/gp/lifewinfaq#Microsoft-Windows-81) that you have time until 16th January 2016 to update to Windows 8.1 to still receive Updates:

> Windows 8.1 falls under the same lifecycle policy as Windows 8, and
>   will reach end of Mainstream Support on January 9, 2018, and end of
>   Extended Support on January 10, 2023. ***With the General Availability of
>   Windows 8.1, customers on Windows 8 have 2 years, until January 12,
>   2016, to move to Windows 8.1 in order to remain supported.***

This is the same like in Windows 7 where you have to install the Sp1 to still receive Updates until 2020.

> **Why are you requiring Windows 8 customers move to Windows 8.1 two years after the General Availability?**
>
> Historically, we’ve had a similar support approach related to Windows
>   service packs; when a Windows service pack is released, Microsoft
>   provides customers 24 months of support for the prior service pack or
>   original RTM version. Unlike service packs that are typically just a
>   collection of fixes, Windows 8.1 has new features and enhancements. We
>   designed Windows 8.1 to give customers an ability to deploy this
>   update in a manner that is similar to how customers deploy service
>   packs, therefore we are applying the existing service pack support
>   policy to Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what you read in that link. The link is not from Microsoft, but from a 3rd party software firm.

Windows 8 itself will still be supported by Microsoft (see the answer of duDE), but the app/program "Classicstart8" will drop support for Windows 8 in two years.

Comment: Absolutely right, +1 !

Comment: you're welcome, @remassido. 
Feel free to mark an answer as accepted, when your question is answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: nope, he read it correctly, you are wrong.